# Starting with a reputation score of 1.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Starting with a reputation score of one on a new side is hard. I can't create my own tags (asking different questions is hared), I can't add more than 1 comment every three minutes and I'm constantly being challenged as a robot.

I think the first 1000 or so users of a stackexchange site should be given a "frontiersman" badge with extra reputation so they can get the site going without the fuss of the 1 reputation point burden.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 200 rep on OldSite (such as SO) when you create an account on NewSite and associate NewSite's account with OldSite's account, you'll be given 100 rep on NewSite.  Looking at your profile, it seems like that should have happened as I see accounts to the other sites on your profile.  Are they not really associated?

Comment: They are associated - I assumed that because the cooking site wasn't programming related, it wouldn't copy some of my rep over. Not entirely sure why it didn't.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try removing the association and re-associating them?  I got the bonus when I created my account, and looking at the Users page, there are others who have 101 rep but have not answered or asked anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me why you would be having this problem. Reputation limits are *severely* relaxed during private beta and somewhat relaxed during public beta.

See for yourself:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

> 1  Vote up
>   1  Leave comments
>   1  Vote down (costs 1 rep)
>   1  Edit community wiki posts
>   1  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
>   1  Create new tags
>   1  Retag questions
>   1  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions

Comment: I couldn't create new tags. Even though I had 1 reputation point, I was told that I needed at least one rep point to do what I needed to do. Maybe a fencepost error.

Comment: @seany ah, I'll check into that. I'd expect to have seen serious complaints earlier for the other sites if that was true, though.

Comment: @seany indeed you're right. :P will check in fix -- checked in, will be deployed in ~ 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it might be hard and unpleasant, but this is required to avoid trolls flooding the site. You have to work a bit to reach a minimum level of reputation to do potentially disruptive things (this means that you have some *reputation* on the site and the community let you enough power to doing such things).

Comment: Which is why only the first few people to join the site should get a rep-bump.